# Introducing delays on sql server db for testing timeouts in API

Tags: sql-server, testing, iis

I have an IIS application that is hosted in a Windows VM which runs queries on a local SQL server. For the purposes of testing timeouts and few other configuration changes, I want to be able to simulate a delay whenever a query is executed on the DB by the IIS. I have researched this for a bit and found the following:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144591/need-to-intentionally-create-blocking-processes-for-testing.

However, this is not working as I cannot see the effective delay in the API response. Note that I am executing the query mentioned in the link above through the local SSMS in the VM.

Queries executed:

Window 1:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT * FROM TestAudit.dbo.TestAT WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Window 2:

```
SELECT TestTId, 
       TestAId, 
       TestST, 
       TestO, 
       TestRC, 
       TestSD 
FROM   TestAudit.dbo.TestAT
WHERE  ( 
              ServerTimestamp >= '2018-10-16 01:48:21.344' 
       AND    ServerTimestamp <= '2018-10-16 01:48:22.344') 
AND    TestAId = '2000093309' 
AND    TestO IN ('A', 'B') 
AND    ( 
              ClientName <> 'Test.Admin' 
       AND    ClientName NOT LIKE '%TestIgnore%');
```

Expecting a delay when executing the second query, given that the first has been executed in a different window. But do not experience any delay.

Comment: The answer in the linked question is marked as a "solution", so it works. To determine why your adaption doesn't work, you need to post what you did.

Comment: @Wolfgang Kais When I execute that query to create a delay and open another window in SSMS to run a select query on the specified table I don't experience any delay.

Comment: You keep repeating yourself. Edit your question and copy and paste the code from your 2 SSMS sessions.

Comment: @Wolfgang Kais, Have updated the question with additional details.

Comment: The second query won't block if the database is set to use READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What is the session transaction isolation level? is read committed snapshot isolation turned on?